# use d3js to update text in div tag

Tags: html, d3.js

In the html, I labeled a div tag

```
<div id='count'>Head count:  </div>
```

My goal is to update the count according to user driven events. In the js file, I have

```
d3.select('#count')
  .append('text')
  .text(users.length);
```

Here `users.length` changes upon user driven events. This is not what I want though. What I want is not 'append' but 'update' the text. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `text()` function on the `#count` selector.

```
d3.select('#count')
    .text('Head Count: ' + users.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  d3.select('#count')  
  .html("Head count: 10; Updated");
},500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='count'>Head count:  </div>
```